# Inheriting T from Generic[T]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have two types of classes, `Data` and `Logic` classes. `Data` class contain only the data without any logic and `Logic` class contains the functions that can modify the data in some way. Because I have a lot of different `Data` and `Logic` classes I wanted to reduce the code size so I tried a little trick.

If I have two `Data` classes:

```
class Facility:
    facilityName: str
    
class User:
    userName: str
```

and also two `Logic` classes:

```
class Getter:
    def getValue(self):
        # some code

class Setter:
    def setValue(self, value: Any):
        # some code
```

Instead of writing a special subclass for every combination of `Data` and `Logic` classes

```
class FacilityGetter(Facility, Getter):
    pass
```

I can add a Generic to the `Logic` classes (or vice-versa)

```
class Getter(Generic[T], T): # Getter inherits T
    def getValue(self):
        # some code
```

and be able to write code like this:

```
def test() -> Getter[Facility]:
    # some code
a = test()
a.facilityName
a.getValue()
```

without getting any type errors inside the IDE.

The problem is, it doesn't work. Is there any way to achieve this without doing something like:

```
class Getter(Generic[T]):
    value: T
    def getValue(self):
        # some code
a = test()
a.value.facilityName
a.getValue()
```

I know I can add the values dynamically but I want my IDE to be able to detect values from Data and Logic classes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some *hacky* way how you can achieve the goal. The core is to dynamically construct class and instantiate it:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, get_args, get_type_hints


class Facility:
    facilityName: str


T = TypeVar("T")


class Getter(Generic[T]):
    def getValue(self):
        return 42


def test() -> Getter[Facility]:
    T = get_args(get_type_hints(test)["return"])[-1]

    return type(
        f"Getter[{T}]",
        (
            Getter,
            T,
        ),
        {**Getter.__dict__, **get_type_hints(T)},
    )()


a = test()

print(a)
print(a.facilityName)
print(a.getValue())
```

Prints:

```
<__main__.Getter[<class '__main__.Facility'>] object at 0x7f57eeb98f50>
<class 'str'>
42
```

Comment: Note, this is *really* slow and memory-hungry. Classes aren't designed to make this kind of usage efficient.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it's hacky way. Most probably I wouldn't use this in production environment.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in which the IDE can recognize the values of both classes, here only Getter's values are available.

Comment: @Orion I'm not sure if this is possible now. But you can try to use union type: `def test() -> type[Union[Facility, Getter]]`  Where Facility and Getter are just normal classes.